# Count number of files in directory and sub director

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the number of files in directory and sub directories, but getting wrong answer.

I have a folder name: `train` which contains 10 sub-folders. Each sub-folder contains 900 files.

When I'm counting the files with the following code, I'm getting 0 files which is wrong (need to be 9000).
It seems that `isfile` doesn't work.
What am I missing ?

```
TRAIN_IMAGES_DIR = 'C:\\test\\train\\'


NUM_OF_FILES = 0
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(TRAIN_IMAGES_DIR):
    for file in files:
        print (file)
        if os.path.isfile(file):                
            NUM_OF_FILES = NUM_OF_FILES + 1
        else:
            print("Folder: ", file)

print (NUM_OF_FILES)
```

I'm using python 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `isfile()` **at all**, because `os.walk()` has already separated directories from files for you. When done correctly, the test will be True *for all elements of the `files` list*.

What goes wrong is that each filename is *relative*, it is just the last element of the path. `os.path.isfile()` can only look in the current working directory for such names, and that's not where those files are actually located. You'd have to use `os.path.join(subdir, file)` to turn the relative filename to an absolute path.

But, again, don't use `isfile()`, that's just double work. `os.walk()` has already sorted out the files out for you.

The following will work to count your files:

```
NUM_OF_FILES = 0
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(TRAIN_IMAGES_DIR):
    NUM_OF_FILES = NUM_OF_FILES + len(files)
```

because you only need to know the length of the list here. You can use `NUM_OF_FILES += len(files)` too to add the length.

Even shorter, using the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
NUM_OF_FILES = sum(len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(TRAIN_IMAGES_DIR))
```

If this produces a *higher than expected* number, then that means you have more files than you expected to have. For example, you may have *hidden* files (on POSIX systems, any file that starts with `.` is hidden from directory listings unless you use `ls -a` or similar techniques to reveal them).

You could perhaps *filter* your files first, on a filename extension; `os.path.splitext(file)` can give you a `(base, ext)` tuple for that. Or just filter out `file[0] == "."` values.

Answer (score 0):

Pathlib glob is slower but handy when you don't need super speed.

```
def __get_files(p:PathOrStr):
    p = Path(p)
    res = [] # result list    
    return p.glob("**/*") # all the files

gen = __get_files(p=r"C:\Users\dj\")

for _ in gen:
     print(_)
```